# How to use Realm Android Adapter with RecyclerView

Tags: android, realm, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am trying to learn using `RecyclerView` with `Realm`. I am following official tutorial from [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters).

But I am facing error in replicating the example itself, when I wrote the program myself.

[image: Realm RecyclerView Adapter Error]

The official `MyRecyclerViewAdapter` example code is posted [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview/MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java) on Realm's Github.

My `SubjectsAdapter` code is -

```
package in.medicalguru.adapters;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import in.medicalguru.MainActivity;
import in.medicalguru.R;
import in.medicalguru.models.TimeStamp;
import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
import io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter;

public class SubjectsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<TimeStamp, SubjectsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final MainActivity activity;

    public SubjectsAdapter(MainActivity activity, OrderedRealmCollection<TimeStamp> data) {
        super(data, true);
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TimeStamp obj = getData().get(position);
        holder.data = obj;
        //holder.title.setText(obj.getSubjectName());
        holder.title.setText(obj.getTimeStamp());
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public TimeStamp data;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //activity.deleteItem(data);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant part of project's `build.grade` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

The relevant part of module's `build.gradle` :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
}
```

Unfortunately, I am very new to Realm and I am unable to understand what exactly does this error mean, so I couldn't even google about it.

Comment: it just says that the `super()` call is missing the `Context` parameter

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Thanks, I got it now. Just for learning, why the mentioned example did not need the `context` in `super`?

Comment: Because they don't actually use that `Context` parameter and [is scheduled to be removed in 1.5.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ hint says first argument in `super` call of your constructor should be `Context`.

try this.

```
public SubjectsAdapter(MainActivity activity, OrderedRealmCollection<TimeStamp> data) {
    super(activity, data, true);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```